# ios Add to homescreen works on my localhost but doesn't work on staging and production website

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-redux, homescreen, home-screen-widget

i'm developing a react -redux app & want add to homescreen to work on live ,currently it only works on localhost.
here's a snippet of my index.html of both public and src folder

```
 <%= require('./html/newrelic.html') %>
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon--precomposed" href="./../apple-touch-icon.png"/>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js"></script>
```

Comment: -precomposed not --precomposed

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="./../apple-touch-icon.png"/>
```

You added an extra `-` to `apple-touch-icon-precomposed`